# laravel 5.2 valid ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

How can we check in Laravel 5.2 if a request is a valid ajax request. In codeigniter ,we could check it like $this->input->is_ajax_request(). Does, Laravel 5.2 has something similar?

Also, I would like to know that how can we validate a request for csrf token. Is it fine if I let my webpage render through the 'web' middleware generating a csrf token and then pass this token as ajax request parameter? Would Laravel take care of validating the token or is there an alternate way around this?

I have checked the laravel 5.2 documentation, and since this is the first time I am dealing with laravel framework, it seems like the documentation assumes that the reader already has a familiarity with earlier versions of the framework. To a new comer like me this is little overwhelming.

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if you need more inputs from me.

Prakhar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this may help you to undestand a very basic way of using AJAX with Laravel.

It's a really old piece of code, but it works jajajaja

Controller side:

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function getRamos(Request $request)
{
    $check = Ramo::find($request->input('ramo'));
    $subramos = Subramo::where('ramo_id', $check->id)->get(['nombre_subramo']);
    if($request->ajax()){
        return response()->json([
            'subramos' => $subramos
        ]);
    }
}
```

In the front:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#ramo').change(function(){
            var ramo, token, url, data;
            token = $('input[name=_token]').val();
            ramo = $('#ramo').val();
            url = '{{route('getRamos')}}';
            data = {ramo: ramo};
            $('#subramos').empty();
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
                data: data,
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: 'JSON',
                success: function (resp) {
                    $.each(resp.subramos, function (key, value) {
                        $('#subramos').append('<option>'+ value.nombre_subramo +'</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Considering "#ramo" as a select input and in use of the style / html package where the token is passed as a hidden input.

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 5.2 (I hope any body get help from this code for Ajax)

Get ajax request in function , two examples of function is under:

First Example

```
public function getLev() {
    if (!Request::ajax())
        return false;
    $result = Input::all();
    $lev_id = (int) $result['lev_id'];
    $invoiceid = (int) $result['invoiceid'];
    return SuppliersController::getLev($invoiceid,$lev_id);//you can do any thing with your variables
//function is working in my case, you case take idea from this function
}
```

Second Example

```
public function deleteInvoice() {
    if (Request::ajax()) {
        $data = Input::all();
        return delete_invoice($data['invoice_id'], $data['reason_text']);//you can do any thing with your variables
    }
    return false;
//function is working in my case, you case take idea from this function
}
```

Include these files on top of the page/controller where you write above ajax related functions:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can we check in Laravel 5.2 if a request is a valid ajax request. In codeigniter ,we could check it like $this->input->is_ajax_request(). Does, Laravel 5.2 has something similar?

The Request class has [an `ajax()` function](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_ajax), so `$request->ajax()` or `Request::ajax()` (depending on how you're getting the request in your controller) will do the trick.

> Also, I would like to know that how can we validate a request for csrf token. Is it fine if I let my webpage render through the 'web' middleware generating a csrf token and then pass this token as ajax request parameter? Would Laravel take care of validating the token or is there an alternate way around this?

Yes, pass the token with the AJAX call and make sure your routes have the CSRF middleware (try a request without a token - it should throw an error). Examples are in the docs for this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: Thanks for the input mate. I checked the documentation further and could find more about the $request->ajax() function.

Comment: @Prakhar Not everything is covered in the docs, they're intended to cover the most commonly used pieces. Sometimes you have to look in the API docs.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you define a HTML form in your application, you should include a hidden CSRF token field in the form so that the CSRF protection middleware will be able to validate the request.

To generate a hidden input field _token containing the CSRF token, you may use the csrf_field helper function:

So to use AJAX request with POST method, you need to pass hidden CSRF token field along with ajax data:

```
<script>

var token="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>";

$.ajax({

  url:url,
  method:'POST',
  data:{
    '_token':token,
    'id':1    
  }


})

</script>
```